# Clash with the matrix theory of solving equation with Cramer's rule

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations, matrix-rank

**Determine the conditions for which the system 
x+y+z=1;
x+2y-z=b;
5x+7y+az=b²;

Has (i)Unique solution
(ii)infinite number of solutions
(iii)no solution**

[page 1 of solution](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yzs5Xm6UMPYPGrRLaqpRtUbEPlMiVTrW/view?usp=drivesdk)

[page 2 of solution](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1l2gFTERE2KmPHPBAfImr0yk9eILXzoCv/view?usp=drivesdk)

[page 3 of solution](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MbNtea-Ru7EhbYXdJnXpMXzrgkki_nVx/view?usp=drivesdk)

Now going into the way I solved 
Let A be the coefficient matrix...

Now as per Cramer's rule for unique solution of the system only the det(A)=0 but now if one looks into the matrix theory... Let A' as shown be the corresponding augmented matrix then...

The system will have unique solution when rank A=rank A'=no. of variables in the system...

Now following the matrix theory if we solve for the unique solution case then apart from a not equals to 1 ( which actually is the answer) we get another condition that is b is not equals to either 3 or -1...

Why is this discrepancy arising??

Answer (score 1):

From your notes, it looks like you calculated $A'$ **only** for the degenerate case $a=1$, which you know from Cramer's rule to not have a unique solution (I see no variable $a$ in those calculations anywhere).

In that case the special values for $b$ distinguish between 'no solution' and 'infinitely many solutions'.

What you get is that for $a=1$ and $b=3,-1$

rank $A =$ rank $A' = 2$, but since the number of variables is $3$, this does not contradict your matrix theory characterization of unique solutions.

Comment: What about the situation when rank A=rank A'=3...this is the situation in particular which i am talking about... If rank A=3 then definitely 'a' is not equals to 1 and for rank A'=3 we have neither b equals to 3 nor -1...(this is as per matrix theory) Now as per Cramer's Rule unique solution exists when 'a' is not equals to 1 irrespective of b... I cannot understand this situation particularly... Matrix theory is giving special information which is useless for unique solution case... What is this? Where am I wrong?

Comment: I cannot understand this situation particularly! Please help me out!!

Comment: "What about the situation when rank A=rank A'=3...this is the situation in particular which i am talking about". Good! Then give an example of that situation, with $a$ and $b$ specified and you give $A$ and '$A'$. Then we can talk about what apparently goes wrong and where you think there is a contradiction. My general remark is apparently not helping, so we need to go to the trenches. Since you think there is a contradiction, you need to provides the specific example, then we can discuss further!

Comment: "rank A'=3 we have neither b equals to 3 nor -1" this is the part where you are incorrect. That is only true for $a=1$, where we know already that rank $A$ = 2. If you have any $a \neq 1$, then *any* $b$ will give you rank $A'$ = 3. You just don't see it because, as I wrote in my answer, you never calculated A' for a general $a$, you've put in $a=1$.

Comment: Thanks .. Thanks... Thanks a lot a lot a lot... "You just don't see it because, as I wrote in my answer, you never calculated A' for a general a, you've put in a=1. " this line is of great importance for me... Thanks a lot a lot a lot once again... I can't tell you how you have helped me...